# Pixels won't add up

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my pixel calculations not adding up.

I have a main div (`#page`) that is: 980px wide
It has a child div (`#content`) that is also: 980px wide

Inside the div (`#content`) there are two divs (`#left-pane`), which is 300px wide and (#right-pane), which is 676 px wide.

Both of them have a 1px border all the way around - looking across the site horizontally this should give 4px in width.

Therefore,

300px + 676px + 4px = 980px

Despite this, my div (`#right-pane`) moves down below the div (`#left-pane`). Why?

I have padding and margin set to NONE on both of them.

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Brazil Learner | The easy was to master Brazilian-Portuguese</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

<div id="top">
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
<ul class="social">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<div class="nav-button"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
<div class="nav-button"><a href="#">Lessons</a></div>
<div class="nav-button"><a href="#">Guides</a></div>
<div class="nav-button"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
</div>

<div id="content">

<div id="left-pane">
</div>

<div id="right-pane">
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
<div>

</div> <!-- Page closer -->

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,p,ul,li,img,h1,h2,h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;   
}

#page {
width: 980px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

/* Top */

#top {
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 30px 30px;
}

.logo {
float: left;
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
}

.social {
float: right;
margin-right: 40px;
}

.social li {
display: inline;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

/* Nav */

#nav {
border: 1px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav-button {
float: left;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 6px;
background-color: grey;
text-align: center;
}

/* Content */

#content {
margin-bottom: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 980px;
}

#left-pane {
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 700px;
border: 1px solid green;
}

#right-pane {
float: right;
width: 676px;
height: 700px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

/* Footer */

#footer {
float: left;
width: 980px;
height: 70px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: So your container is **960** pixels wide, your content is **980** pixels wide, and you're surprised it doesn't fit? :o)

Comment: In what browser are you seeing it move down? [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq2sz/) in Chrome 22, IE 9, and FireFox 13....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work or not, but add this and see if it works.

```
* {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Comment: Very simple solution. Thank you. Does this work on all browsers?

Comment: Yep, it works across all browsers and is very useful. I add it to all my sites by default now. It makes the box model behave like you would expect it to. I wrote a blog post about it if you want to learn a bit more. http://matt-steele.com/blog/box-sizing-border-box

Answer (score 1):

To consider a width of a div, there are 4 comoponents you should think about

1. The width of the div itself (this is where your text will be for example)
2. The padding width (surrounding the width mentioned in point 1 above)
3. The width of your border (surrounding the padding)
4. The margin (surrounding the border)

So, if you search for CSS Box Model (some examples are here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html and here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), you will be able to see the box model that will help you with that. Also using jQuery you can retrieve the width of each section using the following methods: [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/), [.innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/), and [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/). Note you may need to do some calculations to finds border width, padding width, or margin width.

Read CSS documentation and jQuery documentation to have a clearer idea of how those work. Sometimes you may need to utilize jQuery to make the width calculations for you properly if you need some exact values with variable width objects.

Comment: Ummm, I think it does help him look for the right answer. The asker is ommiting padding and margin. So by looking at those, he may be able to find the answer. Also, he can use the three jQuery width methods, including .outerWidth(true), to figure out the width of each of his divs.

Comment: w3schools is a [terrible resource](http://www.w3fools.com), else I'd upvote this.

Comment: Here is the box model from w3.og itself now! http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html (updating the comment just for you)

Comment: I think the OP clearly understands the box model and takes each of the 4 components you outline into account.

Comment: You are probably right, and I am not saying this is THE answer. This is how I approach a problem, and this is why you are allowed a number of answers in this site: to give differnt points of view. In any case, my intention, just like yours and anyone else's, is to provide the best help to the asker.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using to test your site?

I tossed up your code on a fiddle, and it appears just fine in my Firefox, which suggests that you're probably looking at it in IE, and possibly either in a non-standards mode, or an old version.

If that's the case, then it's due to how IE (namely, old versions), handle the box model and math. To IE, 300px + 676px + 4px > 980px . The easiest way to fix this is to reduce something that affects the width by 1-2px, and it will probably fix it.

Comment: Here's the fiddle, because Joel & Co. seem to have added a new....feature. http://jsfiddle.net/nFHMk/

Comment: You need to uncheck the 'normalize CSS' in the JSFiddle because otherwise it'll apply their browser style normalization CSS first.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Unchecking it didn't have any effect - http://jsfiddle.net/nFHMk/1/ (as it shouldn't, since it would stand to reason that they would overlap with the reset the OP has in his code).

Comment: True. But for best results, it's something that shuld be done for all fiddles for consistency.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think you're the first person I've seen that has even said anything about it, TBH.

Comment: Sometimes when the issue ends up being caused by some esoteric browser styling, you'll see a slew of comments along the lines of "can't reproduce in [browser x], check out this fiddle" where the fiddle will have the 'normalization' on.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Chrome